# Should Kubernetes host nodes be able to access services running in the cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am running:

- Kubernetes v1.19.7 (On-premise, VMs. Provisioned via Kubespray)
- MetalLB
- Calico
- nginx-ingress

**Summary**: Services are refusing to respond when queried from the host nodes. Is this even supposed to work? If not I can stop banging my head against this particular wall...

I am able to access service.foo.com from anywhere on my local network, however if I try to use something like cURL to make a request to service.foo.com from any of the host nodes I get "Connection refused" errors (but I can ping the service with no issue). I get the same behavior from within any pod running on the k8s cluster.

This is making things particularly difficult since I'm trying to set up and OIDC provider to use for gating access to the k8s dashboard, and host node needs to be able to query the provider.

### **Network Setup:**

kube service addresses: 10.233.0.0/18
pods cidr: 10.233.64.0/18

**MetalLB config**:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
      - name: default
        protocol: layer2
        addresses:
          - 172.16.31.75-172.16.31.79
```

**Ingress Controller Service described**

```
Name:                     foo-com-ic-nginx-ingress
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=foo-com-ic
  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
  app.kubernetes.io/name=foo-com-ic-nginx-ingress
  helm.sh/chart=nginx-ingress-0.8.0
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=foo-com-ic-nginx-ingress
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.233.48.18
IPs:                      <none>
IP:                       172.16.31.76
LoadBalancer Ingress:     172.16.31.76
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31445/TCP
Endpoints:                10.233.105.18:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31173/TCP
Endpoints:                10.233.105.18:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Local
HealthCheck NodePort:     30406
Events:
  Type    Reason        Age                 From             Message
  ----    ------        ----                ----             -------
  Normal  nodeAssigned  9m4s (x4 over 43m)  metallb-speaker  announcing from node "node4"
```

**Service Ingress described**

```
Name:             my-service
Namespace:        default
Address:          172.16.31.76
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
TLS:
  SNI routes service.foo.com
Rules:
  Host                 Path  Backends
  ----                 ----  --------
  service.foo.com      /   my-service:80 (10.233.96.27:80)
Annotations:           kubernetes.io/ingress.class: service.com
                         meta.helm.sh/release-name: my-service
                         meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------          ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  AddedOrUpdated  46m (x2 over 46m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Configuration for default/my-service was added or updated
```

Comment: where is the "service.foo.com" pointing to? is it poiting to metalLB provided ip, and is configured correctly? are any subnets in your network overlaping (they should not). My best guess so far would be misconfigured network stack. It would be best if you could explain your whole network configuration.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for your response. The networking setup is my inclination as well, but it's a bit confusing since everything works perfectly except from the host nodes themselves.  
I've added some additional information but I'm not sure what exactly would be helpful to list, please let me know if there's any specific information that I should provide.  
I'm still in the exploratory phase and am basically using Kubespray defaults across the board, but I know that's not so helpful if you're not familiar with that project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone comes across this issue while researching their own, I was eventually able to work around this. By chance I noticed that I could cURL the service from the node that the ingress controller pod was running on.

My work-around then was to change my ingress controller's installation kind from "deployment" to "daemonset". Now that the ingress controller pod runs on every node I am able to access the service from every node in the cluster.